# Failed to load resource : the server responded with status of 400

Tags: reactjs, express, post, fetch, registration

```
    import React from 'react';

class Register extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      name: ''
    }
  }

  onNameChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value})
  }

  onEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value})
  }

  onPasswordChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value})
  }

  onSubmitSignIn = () => {
    fetch('https://warm-earth-96837.herokuapp.com/register', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
        name: this.state.name
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(user => {
        if (user.id) {
          this.props.loadUser(user)
          this.props.onRouteChange('home');
        }
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <article className="br3 ba b--black-10 mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-25-l mw6 shadow-5 center">
        <main className="pa4 black-80">
          <div className="measure">
            <fieldset id="sign_up" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
              <legend className="f1 fw6 ph0 mh0">Register</legend>
              <div className="mt3">
                <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input
                  className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100"
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  id="name"
                  onChange={this.onNameChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mt3">
                <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="email-address">Email</label>
                <input
                  className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100"
                  type="email"
                  name="email-address"
                  id="email-address"
                  onChange={this.onEmailChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mv3">
                <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input
                  className="b pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  id="password"
                  onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
                />
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div className="">
              <input
                onClick={this.onSubmitSignIn}
                className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib"
                type="submit"
                value="Register"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </article>
    );
  }
}



export default Register;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');

const register = require('./controllers/register');
const signin = require('./controllers/signin');
const profile = require('./controllers/profile');
const image = require('./controllers/image');

const db = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    connectionString : process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl : true,
  }
});

const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res)=> { res.send('it is working!') })
app.post('/signin', signin.handleSignin(db, bcrypt))
app.post('/register', (req, res) => { register.handleRegister(req, res, db, bcrypt) })
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => { profile.handleProfileGet(req, res, db)})
app.put('/image', (req, res) => { image.handleImage(req, res, db)})
app.post('/imageurl', (req, res) => { image.handleApiCall(req, res)})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ()=> {
  console.log(`app is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import FaceRecognition from './components/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognition';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Signin from './components/Signin/Signin';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
import './App.css';

const particlesOptions = {
  //customize this to your liking
  particles: {
    number: {
      value: 30,
      density: {
        enable: true,
        value_area: 800
      }
    }
  }
}

const initialState = {
  input: '',
  imageUrl: '',
  box: {},
  route: 'signin',
  isSignedIn: false,
  user: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    entries: 0,
    joined: ''
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = initialState;
  }

  loadUser = (data) => {
    this.setState({user: {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      entries: data.entries,
      joined: data.joined
    }})
  }

  calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
    const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
    const image = document.getElementById('inputimage');
    const width = Number(image.width);
    const height = Number(image.height);
    return {
      leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
      topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
      rightCol: width - (clarifaiFace.right_col * width),
      bottomRow: height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height)
    }
  }

  displayFaceBox = (box) => {
    this.setState({box: box});
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input});
      fetch('https://warm-earth-96837.herokuapp.com/imageurl', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          input: this.state.input
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          fetch('https://warm-earth-96837.herokuapp.com/image', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
              id: this.state.user.id
            })
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(count => {
              this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count}))
            })
            .catch(console.log)

        }
        this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  onRouteChange = (route) => {
    if (route === 'signout') {
      this.setState(initialState)
    } else if (route === 'home') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
    }
    this.setState({route: route});
  }

  render() {
    const { isSignedIn, imageUrl, route, box } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <Particles className='particles'
          params={particlesOptions}
        />
        <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        { route === 'home'
          ? <div>
              <Logo />
              <Rank
                name={this.state.user.name}
                entries={this.state.user.entries}
              />
              <ImageLinkForm
                onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
                onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}
              />
              <FaceRecognition box={box} imageUrl={imageUrl} />
            </div>
          : (
             route === 'signin'
             ? <Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
             : <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import FaceRecognition from './components/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognition';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Signin from './components/Signin/Signin';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
import './App.css';

const particlesOptions = {
  //customize this to your liking
  particles: {
    number: {
      value: 30,
      density: {
        enable: true,
        value_area: 800
      }
    }
  }
}

const initialState = {
  input: '',
  imageUrl: '',
  box: {},
  route: 'signin',
  isSignedIn: false,
  user: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    entries: 0,
    joined: ''
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = initialState;
  }

  loadUser = (data) => {
    this.setState({user: {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      entries: data.entries,
      joined: data.joined
    }})
  }

  calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
    const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
    const image = document.getElementById('inputimage');
    const width = Number(image.width);
    const height = Number(image.height);
    return {
      leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
      topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
      rightCol: width - (clarifaiFace.right_col * width),
      bottomRow: height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height)
    }
  }

  displayFaceBox = (box) => {
    this.setState({box: box});
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input});
      fetch('https://warm-earth-96837.herokuapp.com/imageurl', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          input: this.state.input
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          fetch('https://warm-earth-96837.herokuapp.com/image', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
              id: this.state.user.id
            })
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(count => {
              this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count}))
            })
            .catch(console.log)

        }
        this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  onRouteChange = (route) => {
    if (route === 'signout') {
      this.setState(initialState)
    } else if (route === 'home') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
    }
    this.setState({route: route});
  }

  render() {
    const { isSignedIn, imageUrl, route, box } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <Particles className='particles'
          params={particlesOptions}
        />
        <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        { route === 'home'
          ? <div>
              <Logo />
              <Rank
                name={this.state.user.name}
                entries={this.state.user.entries}
              />
              <ImageLinkForm
                onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
                onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}
              />
              <FaceRecognition box={box} imageUrl={imageUrl} />
            </div>
          : (
             route === 'signin'
             ? <Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
             : <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Register Handler Code**

```
const handleRegister = (req, res, db, bcrypt) => {
  const { email, name, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !name || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json('incorrect form submission');
  }
  const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
    db.transaction(trx => {
      trx.insert({
        hash: hash,
        email: email
      })
      .into('login')
      .returning('email')
      .then(loginEmail => {
        return trx('users')
          .returning('*')
          .insert({
            email: loginEmail[0],
            name: name,
            joined: new Date()
          })
          .then(user => {
            res.json(user[0]);
          })
      })
      .then(trx.commit)
      .catch(trx.rollback)
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to register'))
}

module.exports = {
  handleRegister: handleRegister
};
```

**I am getting error 400 when i am trying to register a user.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
i have attached my register.js file
Register.js:26 POST https://warm-earth-96837.herokuapp.com/register 400 (Bad Request)
Register.onSubmitSignIn @ Register.js:26**
The 400 Bad Request Error is an HTTP response status code that indicates that the server was unable to process the request sent by the client due to invalid syntax. As with the dozens of potential HTTP response codes, receiving a 400 Bad Request Error while accessing your own application can be both frustrating and challenging to fix. Such HTTP response codes represent the complex relationship between the client, a web application, a web server, and often multiple third-party web services, so determining the cause of a particular status code can be a difficult, even within a controlled development environment

Comment: Can you please share your controller register.handleRegister code and your postgress model so i can easy to understand your code.

Comment: @ReshamSaharm try debugging by adding console in you catch `.catch(err => { console.log(err); res.status(400).json('unable to register'); })` it maybe db issue

Answer (score 0):

The 400 error happens when, for example, your route signup needs a field "name" and you did not send this field, or when you send a field that, for example, should be a string but you sent an Integer. That is, your request is wrong. Please put here what your route request to sign up the user so we can conclude what field is wrong or what is missing.

Thx and waiting for your response :).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I've attached App.js file.

Comment: Thx, but what fields your https://warm-earth-96837.herokuapp.com/register  route needs to register an user? Are you sure that your route just needs email, password and name? When you call the ```onSubmitSignIn```method all these fields are String? Please check all of this and give me a feedback :)

Comment: yes it only needs name,email and password .all these are strings.

Comment: Content-Length: 59
Content-Type: application/json
Host: warm-earth-96837.herokuapp.com
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36

Comment: Request Payload - {email: "jenny@gmail.com", password: "123", name: "jenny"}
email: "jenny@gmail.com"
name: "jenny"
password: "123"

Comment: General - Request URL: https://warm-earth-96837.herokuapp.com/register
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: 34.200.185.68:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Respose headers - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2021 11:58:19 GMT
Etag: W/"14-gFCh7KY6ogrGj75G9tRL0gWWgt8"
Server: Cowboy
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Powered-By: Express

Comment: this is what it shows when i try to register a user.